# VBscript to click a Javascript link?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

Can somebody please show me how to get my VBScript to click a this link in Javascript.

Below is the source code

```
<td colspan="2" align="right"><a href="Javascript:submitLogon();"onmouseout="document.images['logon'].src='/enrole/en/images/login.gif'; window.status=location; return true" onmouseover="document.images['logon'].src='/enrole/en/images/login_f2.gif'; return true"><img vspace="4" border="0" name="logon" src="/enrole/en/images/login.gif" alt="Login to Identity Manager"></a></td>
```

Im very new to scripting in general and i already know how to click a link with a name or Id tag in the HTML ect but ive not seen this before.

Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: Click means to raise the onclick or the href function?

Comment: Yes, its a automation script and im stuck getting it to actually click the logon button :)

Comment: For Each Button In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") If InStr(Button.getAttribute("onmouseout"), "submitLogon") Then Button.Click Exit For End If                   I really dont know if this is anywhere close ive just been picking at bits from all over the web lol

Comment: VBscript runs on the SERVER. JavaScript runs on the CLIENT. VB cannot click a link.

Comment: Ok so there no way to do this? :/

Comment: Just a tip, posting piece of code as comment is unreadable, when you add code, do so by edit your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking that image inside your link; its name is "logon"...

```
<img vspace="4" border="0" name="logon" src="/enrole/en/images/login.gif" alt="Login to Identity Manager">
```

BTW no way you are using VBScript to click JavaScript you must be using an automation tool or something so you might try **a forum for your tool**, ok?